# DotNetNuke - dnnModal.show arguments

Tags: javascript, popup, dotnetnuke, popupwindow

I want to pass an ID to a pop-up I call using dnnModal.show function.

Im using the current fucnction:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowEditForm(id, rowIndex) {


        javascript: dnnModal.show("Paymentmatchform?popUp=true", false, 250, 450, false);


         return false;

     }
</script>
```

I Want to pas the values of id to the pop-up window somehow and use it there. Please help me out!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
return dnnModal.show('http://www.domain.ir/yourpage.aspx?id=value',/*showReturn*/true,450,700,false,'');
```

hope this help.